# How to play through bluetooth speakers with RPi renderer on lan and openhome/linn android phone control point

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, alsa

Using RPi3b and clean installation of RaspberryPi OS Lite and connecting to network using lan.

Media is stored on NAS and served to lan by minimserver.

I have installed upmpdcli and mpd on RPi and this works correctly using android phone control point connecting to network lan over wifi using BubbleDS as the control app.

Once the playlist on control point has been built and playing started, the phone can be removed or turned off and playing continues for duration of playlist.  All good so far.

My problem is that I can only get the sound to play through the HDMI output and not through bluetooth speakers.

For bluetooth playing I have tried to install armv7-bluez-alsa-osmc.deb with dependencies libbluetooth3 libsbc1 libfdk-aac1 but cannot now get libfdk-aac1 from repo so my bluetooth efforts here have failed.

I did have success with the bluetooth installation on an OSMC(Kodi) OS installation on which I was able to install armv7-bluez-alsa-osmc.deb and all dependencies and can play media through the BT speakers but not using openhome/linn approach.  This setup can only play with the control point remaining connected to lan.

Can anybody help me get the player to play from mpd to bluetooth speakers.  If possible I would prefer to get the Lite OS system to work and only tried the OSMC OS because I had good information and help with that and getting BT to work.